# Object reference becomes null on invoking findViewById() method

Tags: android

I'm learning actionviews and was following this short tutorial:
http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-custom-action-view-to-action-bar-in-android/

But I don't know why the EditText object becomes null at the runtime. Please help me with this.

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /** Create an option menu from res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.items, menu);

        /** Get the action view of the menu item whose id is search */
        View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        /** Get the edit text from the action view */
        EditText txtSearch = ( EditText ) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_search);

        /** Setting an action listener */
        txtSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Search : " + v.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}

items.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:title="Photo"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:title="Video"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:title="Mobile"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_layout"
        />

</menu>

search_layout.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_search"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layouts as well

Comment: I did: search_layout.xml and items.xml. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comment you stated the xml file names are `search_layout.xml` and `items.xml`. Now, in your code, you'll notice this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

And this is important, so listen up: This line of code basically says, here is the **corresponding xml file (layout resource element) that belongs to this java class.** Now, what is the point of this? Well, if you want to access something that is in the content of an xml file called `hello`, and change the image of an image button, you cant do it until you specify **where that image button is.**

XML: I'm what the screen looks like!

Java: I'm what to do with some screen. What screen? Well, that screen is described in the `setContentView` line.

So, as you go deeper into android, you will start to get more and more XML files, and you need to specify which one you are talking about, so that the java (which is the brain of your program) knows what to do and where to do it.

Hope this helped, let me know if it did!

Ruchir

Comment: Thank you for clear explanations, I got the app running!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` layout is referencing to the wrong file. Change to (i guess is that the name of the file) `setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);`